# how to push an element at index 0 of an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have a situation like this,

i have 2 `array1`  as `array1 = ["fruit","vegetables"];`

and

`array2 = [["apple","banana"],["tomato"]];  // index 0:represent fruit i,e (["apple","banana"]), index 1: vegetables i,e (["tomato"])`

**my question** :  how can i `push item` from `array1`  so as to make my `array2` look like this

`[["fruit","apple","banana"],["vegetables","tomato"]];`

with that i can determine `index:0` as `category`.

**MY** `data structure` is  these 2 `array` `array1 = ["fruit","vegetables"];`  AND   `array2 = [["apple","banana"],["tomato"]];`

if i'm able to get `key` `value` pair `array` that would good for me.

my sample data:

```
array1 = ["fruit","vegetables"];


array2 = [["apple","banana"],["tomato"]]; //expected output :[["fruit","apple","banana"],["vegetables","tomato"]];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array#unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) method.

```js
var array1 = ["fruit", "vegetables"],
  array2 = [
    ["apple", "banana"],
    ["tomato"]
  ];

var array3 = array2.map(function(v, i) { // iterate over the array to generate the new array
  var arr = v.slice(); // copy the array
  arr.unshift(array1[i]) // insert element at beginning 
  return arr; /// return generated array
});

console.log(array3)
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you don't want to create a new array then you can avoid the copying part.

```js
var array1 = ["fruit", "vegetables"],
  array2 = [
    ["apple", "banana"],
    ["tomato"]
  ];

array2.forEach(function(v, i) { // iterate over the array 
  v.unshift(array1[i]) // insert element at beginning 
});

console.log(array2)
```

With [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) :

```js
var array1 = ["fruit", "vegetables"],
  array2 = [
    ["apple", "banana"],
    ["tomato"]
  ];

array2.forEach((v, i) => v.unshift(array1[i]));

console.log(array2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [**`Array.map()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [**`Array.unshift()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) .`unshift()` push the data into array `[0]index` position.

```js
array1 = ["fruit","vegetables"];
array2 = [["apple","banana"],["tomato"]]; 

array2.map((a,i) =>  a.unshift(array1[i]))
console.log(array2)
```